# How to get data from a JSON and display in grid via vb6

Tags: json, rest, grid, vb6

I need to get data from a JSON-Object and display some data into MSHFlexGrid. I'm using (VBA-JSON v2.3.1 JsonConverter). [VBA-Json in Github](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON)

Here is the json :

```
{
"status": "OK",
"code": "OK",
"message": "Ok",
"data": {
"messages": [
{
"number": "+9710001529",
"message": "Hello World",
"sender": "+97911308600",
"time": "2022-07-12T20:12:14Z",
"type": "normal"
},
{
"number": "+9710001529",
"message": "Just For Test",
"sender": "+979051931024",
"time": "2022-06-28T23:15:22Z",
"type": "normal"
},
{
"number": "+9710001529",
"message": "Test",
"sender": "+979565547989",
"time": "2022-01-28T16:04:50Z",
"type": "mobilepanel"
},
{
"number": "+9710001529",
"message": "Comment",
"sender": "+979102900089",
"time": "2018-06-16T22:23:23Z",
"type": "normal"
}
]
},
"meta": {
"total": 37,
"pages": 4,
"limit": 10,
"page": 0,
"prev": null,
"next": "http://0.0.0.0:80/v1/inbox?limit=10\u0026page=1"
}
}
```

Here my code :

```
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResp)
MSHFlexGrid1.AddItem Json("data")("messages")(1)("number") & vbTab & Json("data")("messages") 
(1)("message") & vbTab & Json("data")("messages")(1)("sender")
```

The problem is that only the first row of the table is filled with json's data and there is no title for each column. How can I read the json and display them in the MSHFlexGrid as rows and columns with the name of each column?
many thanks

Comment: Could this question be separated from the JSON parsing to just be about loading multiple rows into the `MSHFlexGrid` along with headers?  As for headers, you would likely just have to add headers manually as the first row.  Also, it's been a while for MSHFlexGrid here, but do you need to do something like `MSHFlexGrid1.Rows = MSHFlexGrid1.Rows + 1` to increase the row-count?

Comment: @user51 thanks. The type of grid is not important. Flex grid can be used. Using this code, "MSHFlexGrid1.Rows = MSHFlexGrid1.Rows + 1" only the data of the first line is repeated. If I want all Json's data to be displayed in rows and columns in the grid.

Comment: Oh, if the first item is being **repeated** then simply do something like `For I = 1 to Json("data")("messages").Count: grd.AddItem Json("data")("messages")(I)("number") ...: Next`  That way, you iterate over the Collection.

Comment: What @User51 said: the `.AddItem` method adds **one** row to the grid, so you need to a) add the headline row with column captions yourself first _(hint: have a look at the `.FixedRows` property)_  and b) then you need to loop through the JSON as demonstrated by @User51.

Comment: @User51, It seems that using your code does not work and only repeats the data in grid. In addition, each column does not have a title. "grid1.col and grid1.row" should be used, but I don't know how to use and convert Json's data into MSHFlexGrid1 rows and columns. There are many codes for .net but not for vb6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work?  Long lines broken for clarity.  Notice the header is added separately and MANUALLY, before the loop.  Second thing to note is that instead of doing `Json("data")("messages")(1)`, you are using your loop variable `I` with `Json("data")("messages")(I)`.  You get the number of messages with `.Count`, and loop over them.  This prevents them from being repeated.

You may or may not have to something like `MSHFlexGrid1.Rows = MSHFlexGrid1.Rows + 1`, depending on your grid type, if it simply shows one row.  Unsure on that particular grid control.

```vb
Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strResp)
Dim Header as String
Header = "Number" & vbTab & "Message" & vbTab & "Sender"
MSHFlexGrid1.AddItem Header

For I = 1 to Json("data")("messages").Count
  Dim Line as String
  Line = ""
  Line = Json("data")("messages")(I)("number")
  Line = Line & vbTab 
  Line = Line & Json("data")("messages")(I)("message")
  Line = Line & vbTab 
  Line = Line & Json("data")("messages")(I)("sender")

  MSHFlexGrid1.AddItem Line
Next
```